# Nginx Auth Proxy

Tags: url, redirect, nginx, oauth, proxy

I have multiple services which have their own web-server, listening on different ports, for e.g. :

- http://127.0.0.1:5000  (service A)
- https://127.0.0.1:3000 (service B)

I need a way to restrict access to them without tweaking each of them individually. So, I have an OAuth server hosted as well (port 2333). I have configured the OAuth server to be able to redirect you to a certain URL, if you successfully authenticated through it. So, for e.g. if I access this URL:

https://127.0.0.1:2333/oauth/authorise?service=A&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:5000

It will ask for authentication (or search for cookie) and redirect me to the desired URL. This works OK if I manually access that URL, but I need it automated (every time you try accessing the initial URL, get redirected to the OAuth).

I need the following scenario:

- Insert URL http://127.0.0.1:5000 in browser
- Get redirected to https://127.0.0.1:2333/oauth/authorise?service=A&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:5000
- The OAuth server takes care of the rest

For this, I was thinking of using nginx to redirect, but I don't know how to configure it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How are those services hosted? You have a couple of options:

1. Doing a redirect to (https://127.0.0.1:2333) on the / path for A service (on the source code).
2. Doing a redirect on the server configuration (which is more low level and should be faster)

The first option gives you more control, and you can do other things easily (like checking if the user is logged in). The second option is faster, but some things are harder to implement, as you will modify the server configuration)

Comment: I do not have server {} blocks, since nginx is not hosting the webservers, but rather they are hosted independently. Did I not understand your answer correctly?

Comment: Hi @TotolinCristian I have updated the answer...I supposed those apps were hosted using nginx.